# Creating a dataframe from dbscan clustering results

Tags: python

I have performed a clustering with geospatial data with the dbscan algorithm. You can see the project and the code in more detail here: https://notebook.community/gboeing/urban-data-science/15-Spatial-Cluster-Analysis/cluster-analysis

I would like to calculate the following in a dataframe:

- the area of each cluster. It can be calculated as: (lat_max - lat_min) * (lon_max - lon_min)
- number of points belonging to each cluster

At the moment I have added to the original dataset a column with the cluster to which the coordinate belongs.

```
for n in range(num_clusters):
    df['cluster'] = pd.Series(cluster_labels, index=df.index)
```

Any idea of simple code that would allow me to do this?

Comment: First of all i think that cluster area is not (lat_max - lat_min) * (lon_max - lon_min).
It's more likely to be (lat_max - lat_min) * (lon_max - lon_min) * cos((lat_max + lat_min) / 2) in the first approximation. Cause lats and lons are not symmetric.

Comment: Well I decided to calculate it this simplified way

Comment: There's a consensus on it to be this way

Comment: You can read something about approximations here https://blog.mapbox.com/fast-geodesic-approximations-with-cheap-ruler-106f229ad016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is something like

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'cluster': [0, 1, 2],
    'pts': [5, 6, 10],
    'lat': [45, 47, 45],
    'lon': [24, 23, 20],
})

df = df.groupby('cluster').agg(
    min_lat=('lat', 'min'),
    max_lat=('lat', 'max'),
    min_lon=('lon', 'min'),
    max_lon=('lon', 'max'),
)

df["area"] = (df["max_lat"] - df["min_lat"]) * (df["max_lon"] - df["min_lon"])
```

Comment: I will try it and let you know. Thank you!!

Comment: your code works perfectly. it simply puts me the column "cluster" as index of the dataframe and I don't want it. Is there any way to set cluster as another variable?

Comment: @StackoverflowStackoverflow .reset_index() or as_index=Fasle argument to agg